Permission Error when reading Excel file from Kivy App
thanks in advance.
Im experiencing an issue with an .xlsx file stored in the internal storage of an Android tablet.
This app is built with KivyMD 2.3.0()dev using Buildozer and I tried everything I know, I already edited de .spec file to allow permissions to read and write on storage, I changed file attributes with chmod command on the xlsx file, I used on run permissions in my python code and already allowed file permissions in the tablet itself.
In fact, I can list and read other files like images (.jpeg, .png) but my .xlsx is not appearing when I search for it in the MDFileManager (KivyMD)
This the relevant code:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from PIL import Image as PILImage
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as ExcelImage
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager

#Internal storage where .xlsx file resides
workbook = openpyxl.open('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/template2.xlsx')
ws = workbook.active

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    theme_bg_color: "Custom"
    md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDCard:
        style: "elevated"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .5}
        padding: "4dp"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "240dp", "100dp"
        # Sets custom properties.
        theme_shadow_color: "Custom"
        shadow_color: "green"
        theme_bg_color: "Custom"
        md_bg_color: "white"
        md_bg_color_disabled: "grey"
        theme_shadow_offset: "Custom"
        shadow_offset: (1, -2)
        theme_shadow_softness: "Custom"
        shadow_softness: 1
        theme_elevation_level: "Custom"
        elevation_level: 2
        on_release: app.filemanager()

        MDRelativeLayout:

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "dots-vertical"
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}

            MDLabel:
                text: "Elevated"
                adaptive_size: True
                color: "grey"
                pos: "12dp", "12dp"
                bold: True


class Example(MDApp):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager, select_path=self.select_path
        )

    def filemanager(self):
        self.file_manager.show('/storage/emulated/0/')  # Internal storage where files reside
        self.manager_open = True    # It lists everything except the .xlsx file

    def select_path(self, path: str): # Called when click on the selected file

        with PILImage.open(path) as img: # Adds an image to a cell
            img = img.resize((150, 100), PILImage.LANCZOS)
            img.save("img.png")
        img = ExcelImage("img.png")
        ws.add_image(img, "B2")
        ws["A1"] = "Hola Mundo"
        self.exit_manager()
        workbook.save('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/output.xlsx')

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
 

Example().run()


Cannot open .xlsx file due to permission error and the app crashes; I made another code to opening .xlsx file directly from de MDFileManager and it starts, but as I mentioned, I can see all files except my .xlsx file.
I already changed file attributes using chmod a+xwr 'template2.xlsx'
I already allowed file permissions in the tablet itself.
This is the buildozer.spec file permission lines:
'''
(list) Permissions
(See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
'''
And this is the error log:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/template2.xlsx'

The solution for the error can be two things, the *.xlsx file is protected with some AIP or Protection Label from the original owner of the file, however the error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/template2.xlsx' means that this is not the issue, instead, Python is not authorized to read from the directory specified, just like if the *.xlsx file absolute path is not located there, it depends on the Android target version used if this file will or will not be here, two possible solutions:
Solution one, add the files to find in MDFileManager class because kivymd may not include all natively:
The result: 
The full code:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from PIL import Image as PILImage
import os, pwd

try:
    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as ExcelImage
except:
    pass

#from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager

#Internal storage where .xlsx file resides
try:
    workbook = openpyxl.open('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/template2.xlsx')
    ws = workbook.active

except:
    pass

KV = '''
Screen:

    MDCard:
        style: "elevated"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .5}
        padding: "4dp"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "240dp", "100dp"
        # Sets custom properties.
        theme_shadow_color: "Custom"
        shadow_color: "green"
        theme_bg_color: "Custom"
        md_bg_color: [1,1,1,1] #"white"
        md_bg_color_disabled: [0,0,0,.5] #"grey"
        theme_shadow_offset: "Custom"
        shadow_offset: (1, -2)
        theme_shadow_softness: "Custom"
        shadow_softness: 1
        theme_elevation_level: "Custom"
        elevation_level: 2

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "dots-vertical"
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
                on_release: app.filemanager()

            MDLabel:
                text: "Elevated"
                halign: "center"
                adaptive_size: True
                color: "grey"
                pos: "12dp", "12dp"
                bold: True'''

#Modified File Manager class

__all__ = ("MDFileManager",)

import os
import threading

from PIL import Image

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.properties import (
    ObjectProperty,
    StringProperty,
    ListProperty,
    BooleanProperty,
    NumericProperty,
    OptionProperty,
)
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

from kivymd import images_path
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import BaseListItem, ContainerSupport
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.toast import toast

ACTIVITY_MANAGER = """
#:import os os


<BodyManager@BoxLayout>
    icon: 'folder'
    path: ''
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: ''
    dir_or_file_name: ''
    events_callback: lambda x: None
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ModifiedOneLineIconListItem:
        text: root.dir_or_file_name
        on_release: root.events_callback(root.path)

        IconLeftWidget:
            icon: root.icon
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_color

    MDSeparator:


<LabelContent@MDLabel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    shorten: True
    shorten_from: 'center'
    halign: 'center'
    text_size: self.width, None


<BodyManagerWithPrevious>
    paths: []
    path: ''
    type: 'folder'
    events_callback: lambda x: None

    MDGridLayout:
        id: grid_box
        cols: 3
        row_default_height: (self.width - self.cols * self.spacing[0]) / self.cols
        row_force_default: True
        adaptive_height: True
        padding: dp(4), dp(4)
        spacing: dp(4)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            IconButton:
                mipmap: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(100) if self.source and os.path.split(self.source)[1] == "folder.png" else dp(50)
                source: root.get_source(root.type, label_box_1, root.paths, 1)
                on_release: root.events_callback(os.path.join(root.path, label_box_1.text))
            LabelContent:
                id: label_box_1
                text: os.path.split(root.paths[0])[1].replace('thumb_', '') if len(root.paths) >= 1 else ''

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            IconButton:
                mipmap: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(100) if self.source and os.path.split(self.source)[1] == "folder.png" else dp(50)
                source: root.get_source(root.type, label_2, root.paths, 2)
                on_release: root.events_callback(os.path.join(root.path, label_2.text))
            LabelContent:
                id: label_2
                text: os.path.split(root.paths[1])[1].replace('thumb_', '') if len(root.paths) >= 2 else ''

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            IconButton:
                mipmap: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(100) if self.source and os.path.split(self.source)[1] == "folder.png" else dp(50)
                source: root.get_source(root.type, label_3, root.paths, 3)
                on_release: root.events_callback(os.path.join(root.path, label_3.text))
            LabelContent:
                id: label_3
                text: os.path.split(root.paths[2])[1].replace('thumb_', '') if len(root.paths) >= 3 else ''


<FloatButton>
    anchor_x: 'right'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(56)
    padding: dp(10)

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size:dp(56), dp(56)
        icon: root.icon
        opposite_colors: True
        elevation: 8
        on_release: root.callback()
        md_bg_color: root.md_bg_color


<MDFileManager>
    md_bg_color: root.theme_cls.bg_normal

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(5)

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: '%s' % root.current_path
            right_action_items: [['close-box', lambda x: root.exit_manager(1)]]
            left_action_items: [['chevron-left', lambda x: root.back()]]
            elevation: 10

        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'
            bar_width: dp(4)
            bar_color: root.theme_cls.primary_color
            on_scroll_stop: root._update_list_images()

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                default_size: None, dp(48)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'


<ModifiedOneLineIconListItem>

    BoxLayout:
        id: _left_container
        size_hint: None, None
        x: root.x + dp(16)
        y: root.y + root.height / 2 - self.height / 2
        size: dp(48), dp(48)
"""


class IconButton(ButtonBehavior, AsyncImage):
    pass


class FloatButton(AnchorLayout):
    callback = ObjectProperty()
    md_bg_color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    icon = StringProperty()


class ModifiedOneLineIconListItem(ContainerSupport, BaseListItem):
    _txt_left_pad = NumericProperty("72dp")
    _txt_top_pad = NumericProperty("16dp")
    _txt_bot_pad = NumericProperty("15dp")
    _num_lines = 1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.height = dp(48)


class BodyManagerWithPrevious(BoxLayout):
    def get_source(self, source_type, instance_label, paths, index):
        if source_type == "folder" and instance_label.text != "":
            source = self.icon_folder
        else:
            if len(paths) >= index:
                source = paths[index - 1]
            else:
                source = f"{images_path}transparent.png"
        return source


class MDFileManager(ThemableBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    icon = StringProperty("check")
    """
    The icon that will be used on the directory selection button.

    :attr:`icon` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `check`.
    """

    icon_folder = StringProperty(f"{images_path}folder.png")
    """
    The icon that will be used for folder icons when using ``previous = True``.

    :attr:`icon` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `check`.
    """

    exit_manager = ObjectProperty(lambda x: None)
    """
    Function called when the user reaches directory tree root.

    :attr:`exit_manager` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.ObjectProperty`
    and defaults to `lambda x: None`.
    """

    select_path = ObjectProperty(lambda x: None)
    """
    Function, called when selecting a file/directory.

    :attr:`select_path` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.ObjectProperty`
    and defaults to `lambda x: None`.
    """

    ext = ListProperty()
    """
    List of file extensions to be displayed
    in the manager. For example, `['py', 'kv']` - will filter out all files,
    except python scripts and Kv Language.

    :attr:`ext` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.ListProperty`
    and defaults to `[]`.
    """

    search = OptionProperty("all", options=["all", "files"])
    """
    It can take the values 'dirs' 'files' - display only directories
    or only files. By default, it displays and folders, and files.
    Available options are: `'all'`, `'files'`.

    :attr:`search` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.OptionProperty`
    and defaults to `all`.
    """

    current_path = StringProperty(os.getcwd())
    """
    Current directory.

    :attr:`current_path` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `/`.
    """

    use_access = BooleanProperty(True)
    """
    Show access to files and directories.

    :attr:`use_access` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.BooleanProperty`
    and defaults to `True`.
    """

    previous = BooleanProperty(False)
    """
    Shows only image previews.

    :attr:`previous` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.BooleanProperty`
    and defaults to `False`.
    """

    _window_manager = None
    _window_manager_open = False

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.history = []  # directory navigation history
        # If False - do not add a directory to the history -
        # The user moves down the tree.
        self.history_flag = True
        toolbar_label = self.ids.toolbar.children[1].children[0]
        toolbar_label.font_style = "Subtitle1"
        self.ext = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg",".xlsx"]
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.app.user_data_dir, "thumb")):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.app.user_data_dir, "thumb"))
        action_button = FloatButton(
            callback=self.select_directory_on_press_button,
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
            icon=self.icon,
        )
        self.add_widget(action_button)

    def show(self, path):
        """Forms the body of a directory tree.

        :param path: The path to the directory that will be opened in the file manager.
        """

        dirs, files = self.get_content(path)

        if self.previous:
            threading.Thread(target=self._create_previous, args=(path,)).start()
            split_dirs = self._split_list(dirs, 3)
            split_files = self._split_list(files, 3)

        self.current_path = path
        manager_list = []

        if dirs == [] and files == []:  # selected directory
            pass
        elif not dirs and not files:  # directory is unavailable
            return

        if self.previous:
            for list_dirs in split_dirs:
                manager_list.append(
                    {
                        "viewclass": "BodyManagerWithPrevious",
                        "path": path,
                        "icon_folder": self.icon_folder,
                        "paths": list_dirs,
                        "type": "folder",
                        "events_callback": self.select_dir_or_file,
                        "height": dp(105),
                    }
                )
            for list_files in list(split_files):
                manager_list.append(
                    {
                        "viewclass": "BodyManagerWithPrevious",
                        "path": path,
                        "icon_folder": self.icon_folder,
                        "paths": list_files,
                        "type": "files",
                        "events_callback": self.select_dir_or_file,
                        "height": dp(105),
                    }
                )
        else:
            for name in dirs:
                _path = path + name if path == "/" else path + "/" + name
                access_string = self.get_access_string(_path)
                if "r" not in access_string:
                    icon = "folder-lock"
                else:
                    icon = "folder"

                manager_list.append(
                    {
                        "viewclass": "BodyManager",
                        "path": _path,
                        "icon": icon,
                        "dir_or_file_name": name,
                        "events_callback": self.select_dir_or_file,
                    }
                )
            for name in files:
                _path = path + name if path == "/" else path + "/" + name
                manager_list.append(
                    {
                        "viewclass": "BodyManager",
                        "path": _path,
                        "icon": "file-outline",
                        "dir_or_file_name": name,
                        "events_callback": self.select_dir_or_file,
                    }
                )
        self.ids.rv.data = manager_list

        if not self._window_manager:
            self._window_manager = ModalView(
                size_hint=(1, 1), auto_dismiss=False
            )
            self._window_manager.add_widget(self)
        if not self._window_manager_open:
            self._window_manager.open()
            self._window_manager_open = True

    def count_ext(self, path):
        ext = os.path.splitext(path)[1]
        if ext != "":
            if ext.lower() in self.ext or ext.upper() in self.ext:
                return True
        return False

    def get_access_string(self, path):
        access_string = ""
        if self.use_access:
            access_data = {"r": os.R_OK, "w": os.W_OK, "x": os.X_OK}
            for access in access_data.keys():
                access_string += (
                    access if os.access(path, access_data[access]) else "-"
                )
        return access_string

    def get_content(self, path):
        """Returns a list of the type [[Folder List], [file list]]."""

        try:
            files = []
            dirs = []

            if self.history_flag:
                self.history.append(path)
            if not self.history_flag:
                self.history_flag = True

            for content in os.listdir(path):
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, content)):
                    if self.search == "all" or self.search == "dirs":
                        dirs.append(content)
                else:
                    if self.search == "all" or self.search == "files":
                        if len(self.ext) != 0:
                            try:
                                if self.count_ext(content):
                                    if self.previous:
                                        files.append(
                                            os.path.join(
                                                self.app.user_data_dir,
                                                "thumb",
                                                f"thumb_{content}",
                                            )
                                        )
                                    else:
                                        files.append(content)
                            except IndexError:
                                pass
                        else:
                            files.append(content)
            return dirs, files
        except OSError:
            self.history.pop()
            return None, None

    def close(self):
        """Closes the file manager window."""

        self._window_manager.dismiss()
        self._window_manager_open = False

    def select_dir_or_file(self, path):
        """Called by tap on the name of the directory or file."""

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            self.select_path(path)
            return

        self.current_path = path
        self.show(path)

    def back(self):
        """Returning to the branch down in the directory tree."""

        if len(self.history) == 1:
            path, end = os.path.split(self.history[0])
            if end == "":
                self.close()
                self.exit_manager(1)
                return
            self.history[0] = path
        else:
            self.history.pop()
            path = self.history[-1]
        self.history_flag = False
        self.select_dir_or_file(path)

    def select_directory_on_press_button(self, *args):
        """Called when a click on a floating button."""

        self.select_path(self.current_path)

    def _update_list_images(self):
        self.ids.rv.refresh_from_layout()

    def _split_list(self, l, n):
        if l:
            n = max(1, n)
            return (l[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n))
        else:
            return []

    def _create_previous(self, path):
        if "r" not in self.get_access_string(path):
            toast("PermissionError")
            return
        for image in os.listdir(path):
            _path = os.path.join(path, image)
            if os.path.isfile(_path):
                if self.count_ext(_path):
                    path_to_thumb = os.path.join(
                        self.app.user_data_dir, "thumb", f"thumb_{image}"
                    )
                    if not os.path.exists(path_to_thumb):
                        im = Image.open(_path)
                        im.thumbnail((200, 200))
                        im.save(path_to_thumb, "PNG")


Builder.load_string(ACTIVITY_MANAGER)
####Modification complete


class Example(MDApp):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager, select_path=self.select_path
        )

    def filemanager(self):
        self.file_manager.show(pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir)  # Internal storage where files reside
        self.manager_open = True    # It lists everything except the .xlsx file

    def select_path(self, path: str): # Called when click on the selected file

        with PILImage.open(path) as img: # Adds an image to a cell
            img = img.resize((150, 100), PILImage.LANCZOS)
            img.save("img.png")
        img = ExcelImage("img.png")
        ws.add_image(img, "B2")
        ws["A1"] = "Hola Mundo"
        self.exit_manager()
        workbook.save('/storage/emulated/0/Documents/output.xlsx')

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
 

Example().run()

There shouldn't be more Permission denied error, if the error still persists it will be a good idea to get the directory or home directory using pujnius:
from jnius import autoclass
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

#get permission from user
request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

#using Java android.os.Environment, get the right storage directory and pass it to MDFileManager
Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
home_directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

print(home_directory)

